# Angular UI Grid expanded subgrid remain expanded after refresh

Tags: refresh, angular-ui-grid, expand, expandable

I am using the Angular UI grid to display a grid of data, with subgrids that can be expanded. When the subgrid(s) is expanded, if I hit the refresh button to refresh grid, the subgrid(s) become unexpaned (basically back to its original state). How do I make the subgrids remain expanded if the row(s) was expanded, after refresh?

Thank you!